# Pull values from a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column for which I need to pull the R- value.

What would be the best way to do this?

I feel like I'm close with this but having issues getting what I need

Basically need the R- value, can be different characters long, up until the Control lab.

See example below.

```sql
select SUBSTR( err_desc, 57, INSTR (err_desc, 'Control Lab:', 1, 1)-1)
from error_log
where sql_err_text = 'EXCEEDED VARIANCE LIMIT'
and year = '2022';
```

Example would be:

```
Plant: 649 Order: 2HC2204018 Year: 2022 Cycle: 01  Raw: R-66-59-18 Control Lab: WH Variance Warning: 50 Variance Limit: 100
```

Required output: `R-66-59-18`

```
Plant: 650 Order: 9GM2202004 Year: 2022 Cycle: 03  Raw: R-401059 Control Lab: GR
```

Required output: `R-401059`

Tried SQL above. Was getting more characters than expected.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT err_desc, REGEXP_SUBSTR(err_desc, 'Raw: (R(-[0-9]+)+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS output
FROM error_log
WHERE sql_err_text = 'EXCEEDED VARIANCE LIMIT' AND year = '2022';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the value from the first key-value pair where the key ends in `Raw` then you can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       CASE
       WHEN spos = 0 THEN NULL
       WHEN epos = 0 THEN SUBSTR(value, spos + 6)
       ELSE               SUBSTR(value, spos + 6, epos - spos - 6)
       END AS raw_value
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         ' ' || value AS value,
         INSTR(' ' || value, ' Raw: ') AS spos,
         INSTR(' ' || value, ' ', INSTR(' ' || value, ' Raw: ') + 6) AS epos
  FROM   table_name
)
```

or, less to type but regular expressions are much slower to execute:

```sql
SELECT id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(^| )Raw: (\S+)', 1, 1, NULL, 2) AS raw_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, value ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Plant: 649 Order: 2HC2204018 Year: 2022 Cycle: 01  Raw: R-66-59-18 Control Lab: WH Variance Warning: 50 Variance Limit: 100' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Plant: 650 Order: 9GM2202004 Year: 2022 Cycle: 03  Raw: R-401059 Control Lab: GR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Plant: 651 Not Raw: NOT-THIS Raw: XYZ-123' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| ID | RAW_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | R-66-59-18 |
| 2 | R-401059 |
| 3 | NOT-THIS |

*Note: If you have multiple key-value pairs which end in `Raw` then this (and the answers by other people) will get confused as to which key you want and return the first one that matches `Raw`.*

---

If you want all the key-value pairs (assuming you use `:`  to delimit between the key-value pairs and each value ends after the next space character) then you can use:

```sql
WITH bounds (id, value, spos, delim_pos, epos) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         1,
         INSTR(value, ': ', 1),
         INSTR(value, ' ', INSTR(value, ': ', 1) + 2)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         epos + 1,
         INSTR(value, ': ', epos + 1),
         INSTR(value, ' ', INSTR(value, ': ', epos + 1) + 2)
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
) SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order_id,
SELECT id,
       TRIM(SUBSTR(value, spos, delim_pos - spos)) AS key,
       CASE epos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(value, delim_pos + 2)
       ELSE SUBSTR(value, delim_pos + 2, epos - delim_pos - 2)
       END AS value
FROM   bounds;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| ID | KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Plant | 649 |
| 1 | Order | 2HC2204018 |
| 1 | Year | 2022 |
| 1 | Cycle | 01 |
| 1 | Raw | R-66-59-18 |
| 1 | Control Lab | WH |
| 1 | Variance Warning | 50 |
| 1 | Variance Limit | 100 |
| 2 | Plant | 650 |
| 2 | Order | 9GM2202004 |
| 2 | Year | 2022 |
| 2 | Cycle | 03 |
| 2 | Raw | R-401059 |
| 2 | Control Lab | GR |
| 3 | Plant | 651 |
| 3 | Not Raw | NOT-THIS |
| 3 | Raw | XYZ-123 |

If you only want the `Raw` values after getting all the keys then you can use a filter:

```
WITH bounds (id, value, spos, delim_pos, epos) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         1,
         INSTR(value, ': ', 1),
         INSTR(value, ' ', INSTR(value, ': ', 1) + 2)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         epos + 1,
         INSTR(value, ': ', epos + 1),
         INSTR(value, ' ', INSTR(value, ': ', epos + 1) + 2)
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
) SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order_id,
key_value_pairs (id, key, value) AS (
  SELECT id,
         TRIM(SUBSTR(value, spos, delim_pos - spos)),
         CASE epos
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR(value, delim_pos + 2)
         ELSE SUBSTR(value, delim_pos + 2, epos - delim_pos - 2)
         END
  FROM   bounds
)
SELECT *
FROM   key_value_pairs
WHERE  key = 'Raw';
```

Which outputs:

| ID | KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Raw | R-66-59-18 |
| 2 | Raw | R-401059 |
| 3 | Raw | XYZ-123 |

Which will get the correct key if there are multiple ending in `Raw`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xb8KymGf)

Answer (score 0):

Option with the `substr` + `instr` combination; you have to find where `Raw` starts, and then subtract `Control` and `Raw` position (to find substring length). `+5` (as well as `-5`) represents "Raw", colon and space. `+1` is here to properly set substring length.

```
SQL> with error_log (err_desc) as
  2    (select 'Plant: 649 Order: 2HC2204018 Year: 2022 Cycle: 01  Raw: R-66-59-18 Control Lab: WH Variance Warning: 50 Variance Limit: 100' from dual union all
  3     select 'Plant: 650 Order: 9GM2202004 Year: 2022 Cycle: 03  Raw: R-401059 Control Lab: GR' from dual
  4    )
  5  select substr(err_desc, instr(err_desc, 'Raw') + 5,
  6                          instr(err_desc, 'Control') - instr(err_desc, 'Raw') - 5 + 1
  7               ) result
  8  from error_log;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
R-66-59-18 C
R-401059 C

SQL>
```